# Charge and Sign of a pith ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Could really use some help on this question. I don’t even know where to start.[image]

Comment: It is recommended that you avoid using images to make the questions searchable and for the homework-like questions you will only get help if you show your work and thoughts.

Comment: Ok, I’ll keep this in mind

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well do you know about forces, acceleration and mass? Clue: $F = ma$

Do you know how to get the force on a charged object in an electric field? Clue: $F = Eq$

This is not a free homework answering site, so I will not do the problem for you, but with these two equations you should be able to understand what is going on and get the answer required by yourself.